# JavaScript issue (CSP warn) in Firefox OS simulator

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, content-security-policy, firefox-os

I am currently testing the [Area Tweet tutorial application](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Apps/Tutorials/General) (you can find the full source code by following the [Creating the Area Tweet app](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Apps/Tutorials/General/Creating_the_Area_Tweet_app) link) on Firefox OS and I am encountering the following issue: the application does the call to the Twitter API, but does not receive a response, but the following **WARN/ ERROR**:

```
[JavaScript Warning: "CSP WARN:  
Directive script-src app://myapp1002.gaiamobile.org violated by 
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=twitterCallback&q=test&_=1360318777176"]
```

What is the issue here? Is this a hint for not receveing a response to the API request or is there something else? I tested the application on both Firefox and Chrome browsers (on Windows) and it works fine.

I might also add that I tested the [Firefox OS Boilerplate App](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/01/introducing-the-firefox-os-boilerplate-app/) and this one seems to work just fine. The only difference I see between these two web applications is that Area Tweet uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), while the boilerplate one does not. One modification that I did to the original source code of Area Tweet is that I load the jQuery libraries from *localhost* (to comply with the Mozilla packaging policy), but that does not seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your `manifest.webapp` request for `network-http` permission (this would allow your app to disable `same origin policy`) and use reqular json request to twitter (without `callback`parameter).

Answer (score 0):

did you have any inline script in html file since you try to make a packaged app? packaged app don't allow inline script.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Apps/Packaged_apps

Comment: No, there is no inline script; the HTML is the same as in the specified tutorial.